# Mac OS App crashes when saving too many new NSManagedObjects

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

I'm trying to write an app that enumerates through folders and items which are dragged onto the main app window and then places a new entry for each PDF it finds into my Core Data database which in turn populates an NSTableView. To cut a long story short[er], I've got to a stage where I can safely drag a few items into the window and the database gets saved, allowing me to restart the app time after time.

The problem I have is that if I were to [say] drag my Documents folder onto the window it all appears to work but when I quit and attempt to restart then it crashes out with a

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address-0x7fff6f11dff8
```

The code I'm currently using (specifically written for debugging this matter) is:

```
    NSError *error;
    id firstObject = [draggedStuff objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDictionary *fileAttribs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:firstObject error:&error];
    if ([[fileAttribs valueForKey:NSFileType] isEqualTo:NSFileTypeDirectory]) {
        NSManagedObject *aNewFolder = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:kFOLDERS_ENTITY inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
        [aNewFolder setValue:firstObject forKey:kFOLDER_PATH];
        NSArray *directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:firstObject error:&error];
        assert(!error);
        [directoryContents enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            CFStringRef fileExtension = (__bridge CFStringRef) [obj pathExtension];
            CFStringRef fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);
            if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypePDF)) {
                NSManagedObject *aDocument = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity [NSEntityDescription entityForName:kDOCO_ENTITY inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
                [aNewPicture setValue:obj forKey:@"docoPath"];
            }
            CFRelease(fileUTI);
            if (idx % 20 == 0) {
                NSError *error;
                [[self managedObjectContext] save:&error];
                assert(!error);
            }
        }];
    }
```

Initially, I had this in an NSOperation subclass with the relevent checking for user cancellation but I've moved it to the main thread just to make sure that it's not something to do with that, so, yes, it is currently not a user-friendly piece of code.

The crashing is definitely connected to the number of items that `directoryContents` returns with as it works absolutely fine if I drag a folder with only a matter of 20 or so items inside it. If `directoryContents` holds a matter of around 200 files or more then Core Data doesn't seem to save it correctly and corrupts the storedata file which needs to be Trashed before I can restart the app.

The `if (idx % 20 == 0)...` can be changed to save with more or less NSManagedObjects waiting to be saved but with the same results as well.

I've also tried using an NSDirectoryEnumerator with the same results: the corruption is always connected with the number of items in the folder.

I like Core Data, but sometimes I lose my way so any help is much appreciated especially given the length of this post!

Todd.

Comment: Have you tried Instruments' zombies? It may help you identify why you ends up with a bad access.

Comment: Thanks Fabrice. I've never used Zombies (and I need some more time to fully understand it) - when I tried it, though I got a 'different crash' and that's led me to my answer! You pointed me in the right direction even if it was indeirectly :)

Comment: glad to have helped a tiny bit. Zombies and memory guards are of a tremendous help when dealing with memory issues like this one, do not hesitate to use them, they can even hilight bugs you wouldn't have noticed otherwise (not you, but your users yup ;).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was much simpler than I thought: I'd managed to wire up my NSTable incorrectly.

I'd connected both the Table View and the Table column in the NIB to the entity.... Oops.